# externalizing configurations for test.datasource

Tags: grails

I have been able externalize DataSource configurations for development environment by updating grails.config.locations in Config.groovy and then setting specific configurations in .grails/${appName}-config.properties as following:

```
dataSource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
dataSource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost/db-dev
dataSource.username = root
dataSource.password = pass
```

For the 'test' environment, i have different Database so i would like to updated  test.dataSource.url accordingly but this doesn't work. It still takes the 'dev' dataSource.url when running 'grails test' mode(i.e. grails test dgm-update). How to externalize test environment DataSource configuration?

Thank You for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grails.config.locations = ["file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config-${grails.util.Environment.current.name}.properties"]
```

and then put nested files for each env:

```
/home/me/.grails/myapp-config-dev.properties
/home/me/.grails/myapp-config-test.properties
/home/me/.grails/myapp-config-production.properties
```

Comment: ...just to note it was 'development' instead of 'dev' for Grails 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Groovy external configuration, i.e. ".grails/${appName}-config.groovy" with environment specific DSL:

```
environments {
    test {
        dataSource {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sergei. The strange thing is that on my windows machine .grails/${appName}-config.groovy configuration does not work. I haven't spent time investigating since .grails/${appName}-config.properties does work